# python mechanize import failing with python 2.x

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, mechanize, mechanize-python

Mechanize is not working with python 2.x while using "Browser" in mechanize failing.

```
import re
from mechanize import Browser

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whey_protein")

response1 = br.follow_link(text_regex=r"protein\s*shop", nr=1)
assert br.viewing_html()
print(br.title())
print(response1.geturl())
print(response1.info())
print(response1.read()) )
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\test\Mechnize_bt.py", line 2, in
>
> from mechanize import Browser
>
> ImportError: cannot import name Browser

Comment: please post the full traceback

Comment: Do you have a local file named mechanize.py in the same folder as your script?